# Code to open URL, read META & write to text file running out of memory. Need help freeing.(VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, memory-management, memory-leaks, webbrowser-control, out-of-memory

I have a file of about 52k links. I would like to open the links, read a few meta values and write them into a text file.

Code seemed simple enough but as soon as it starts memory starts climbing slowly until it runs out.
I open the file and read to a table and loop through that.

Here's some code with my attempts in it, if that will help diagnose my problem.

```
    Private Sub Bob_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler wbScrape.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf ScrapeDocument)
    wbScrape.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True

    Dim Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(LinkFileName)
    For Each line As String In Lines
        LinkList.Add(line)
    Next

    lblCount.Text = LinkList.Count.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    GetScrapePage()
End Sub

Private Sub GetScrapePage()
    lblCount.Text = LinkList.Count.ToString
    Link = LinkList.First.ToString
    wbScrape.Url = New Uri(Link)
End Sub

Private Sub ScrapeDocument(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim parent_url As String = ""
    Dim og_id As String = ""
    Dim og_description As String = ""
    Dim ProductLineOutput As String = ""
    Dim LinkLineOutput As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim ProductLineOutputPrevious As String = "1st"

    Dim Elems As HtmlElementCollection

    Elems = wbScrape.Document.GetElementsByTagName("META")
    parent_url = wbScrape.Url.ToString()

    For Each elem As HtmlElement In Elems
        i = i + 1

        Dim NameStr As String = elem.GetAttribute("name")
        Dim PropertyStr As String = elem.GetAttribute("property")

        If ((NameStr IsNot Nothing) And (NameStr.Length <> 0)) Or ((PropertyStr IsNot Nothing) And (PropertyStr.Length <> 0)) Then
            If NameStr.ToLower().Equals("og:id") Then og_id = elem.GetAttribute("content").ToString
            If PropertyStr.ToLower().Equals("og:description") Then og_description = Chr(34) & elem.GetAttribute("content").ToString & Chr(34)
        End If

        If og_description <> "" Or i >= 100 Then Exit For

    Next

    ProductLineOutput = parent_url & "," & og_id & "," & og_description

    If ProductLineOutputPrevious <> "" Then
        If (ProductLineOutputPrevious <> ProductLineOutput) And parent_url.Contains("foo") Then
            Dim sw As StreamWriter
            sw = File.AppendText(ExportFileName)
            sw.WriteLine(ProductLineOutput)
            sw.Flush()
            sw.Close()
            sw.Dispose()
        End If
    End If

    ProductLineOutputPrevious = ProductLineOutput
    parent_url = ""
    og_id = ""
    og_description = ""
    i = 0
    ProductLineOutput = ""

    LinkList.Remove(Link)

    If LinkList.Count > 0 Then
        GetScrapePage()
    Else
        MsgBox("Complete")
        wbScrape.Dispose()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [DocumentCompleted](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=documentcompleted&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx&ei=d0b9Ueq3HM7lygHi7oH4Cg&usg=AFQjCNFRkSAb9MWOSnNF4sDlRWIoHdjxyQ&bvm=bv.50165853,d.aWc) event for the WebBrowser not a loop. Put your processing code in the `DocumentCompleted` event. The way I would run many links would be to store the links in a `List(Of T)` and once you fill it you fire off the first navigation on the first element, in the `DocumentCompleted` event you remove the first element in List if it is not empty and then navigate to the first element. This way you go one at a time and the processor frees resources with each iteration.

Comment: And that will that fix the memory issue?

Comment: It would be the first thing I would try. Since that loop looks like the culprit. Also don't call GC.Collect - you don't need it here and that can be a performance hit as well.

Comment: Thanks Don, tried it out. But the problem remains. That way is a lot cleaner but it still nails the memory after 110-120 links. Gotta be a memory leak in the broswer(?). On a side note, doing it that way, if there is a hiccup - a "real" instance of IE opens with the url.

Comment: Are you making a new `WebBrowser` each loop like it shows above? You should be using only one and thats why I was using it's `DocumentCompleted` event so it's done navigating then gather data, then move to next link, rinse - repeat!

Comment: In your `GetScrapePage()` method you are making a new `WebBrowser`. Have you tried to use just one and just make it navigate to each link?

Comment: I've updated the code in the question - and it does run for about 700 before it runs out of memory. That's a huge improvement. Do you see anything else in there?

Comment: Try replacing the `Lines` object with a normal `StreamReader` and use the `Using/End Using` block for it and the other one. I know your disposing the other one this is just a simple way to do it automatically.